# Is it possible to print the created query, like shows up in error messages?

Tags: rethinkdb

I really like how the error messages include a text string representing what the ReQL code looks like. Is it possible to get at this without forcing an error?

#### Example Error message:

```
RqlRuntimeError: No attribute `colors` in object:
{...}
in:
r.db("r_g").table("items").group("collection").ungroup().map(function(var_0) { return var_0("group").object(var_0("reduction")); }).concatMap(function(var_1) { return var_1("colors"); })
```

I'm wanting to get at the value after "in:" shown before I `run()` the query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `.toString()` like `query.toString()` (without `.run(...)`)

It should use the same code as the one used to generate backtraces.

I opened an issue this morning to add it in the docs, it is somehow missing -- https://github.com/rethinkdb/docs/issues/354